# Python PIP not showing pypi package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

**Short Question**

Is there a delay between when a package is added to PyPi and its availability via pip?

**Background**

I have recently pushed a [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qThread/) up to PyPi.  From what I tell there were no errors with this step (it registered OK), but I cannot use pip to install the package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This blog post](https://jamiecurle.co.uk/blog/my-first-experience-adding-package-pypi/) describes the possible problem you are facing. You probably have the same problem and forgot to upload your package, but only registered it, because the package you linked has no files to download.

The solution (taken from the above linked blog post) is to use the command

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Comment: Looking back it looks like I did miss the upload command.  I'll test that and accept it if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Works. Just tried out myself :) Will take a look into your library

Comment: Just tried it as well.  Thanks again.  Note that the library isn't ground breaking :) Just something that I have used in nearly every python project in the last year.  Its also in the alpha stages.

Comment: For the record, I pushed a package to PyPI and it took pip about 15 minutes to see it.